# update xml value with new value in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to post xml request with new updated value from existing xml.
my default payload is: [https://pastebin.com/rDjb0HSH](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

`headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml' } response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False) print(response.text)`

Actually I want to post with new AcctId and 2022-12-13T16:21:10.813 with current datetime.

I tried with above code and return success result but when I modify xml value of 0015151641988001 with new acctid using string concatenate it returned error.

Comment: When I contacted without in function it works but same copy is not working on function body

Comment: "it returned error" - What error? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I solved it by stripped